# How to deal with out of vocabulary words in nlp?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have a multi-label dataset that contains a lot of out-of-vocabulary words. The dataset is basically from a user forum site. The columns are post_title, post_description and tags. I want to predict the tags using machine learning models. But as the dataset contains many out-of-vocabulary words, the models are giving me very poor results. So what should I do in this case?

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.